# Debezium best practice for microservices DB (multiple db instance)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have 50+ micro services and each service has its own database server. I'm going to implement Debezium on VMs (3 VMs for distributed execution). Kubernetes is not in the solution right now for debezium.

So as the best practice for debezium, Can I deploy debezium connector for each service? 50+ connectors will be deployed or any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I deploy debezium connector for each service?

Yes, you can deploy a Kafka Connect cluster and have as many Connectors, such as Debezium, as needed and resources will allow.